# Tag name of New products list of Magento

Tags: magento

In my Magento website I've create a "New products" list in my homepage. I want to print, under every product, its related tag. How can I do this?

Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Check below code may be help you

```
$model=Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    $tags= $model->getResourceCollection()
        ->addPopularity()
        ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
        ->addProductFilter($_product->getId())
        ->setFlag('relation', true)
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->setActiveFilter()
        ->load();
      foreach($tags as $tag):
            echo $tag->getName().'<br/>';
        endforeach;
```

Comment: Yes yes yes!! it'all right! Thank you so much! Have a nice day!!